# New style for a new GWT component

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am using SmartGWT 2.4, and I have two types of TabSet(s), each one has a different look and feel, and I am facing a problem implementing that.

The new TabSet has been implemented as the following :

```
public class MainTabSet extends TabSet{
    public MainTabSet(){
        super.setStylePrimaryName("MainTabSet");
        build();
    }

    private void build(){
        setMargin(6);
        setWidth100();
        setHeight100();  
        setStyleName("nt-main-tabset");
        Tab inboxTab = new Tab("Inbox");
        inboxTab.setPane(new InboxPane().get());
     }
}
```

based on the last paragraph (Multiple looks for the same component type) [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Skinning.html) :

I've defined a new class that holds the same primary name I used above :

```
isc.defineClass("MainTabSet", "TabSet");
```

and then I've added some properties to it :

```
    isc.MainTabSet.addProperties({
        tabBarThickness:100,
        scrollerButtonSize:100,
        pickerButtonSize:100,

        symmetricScroller:false,
        symmetricPickerButton:false,

        scrollerSrc:"nothing",
        pickerButtonSrc:"nothingg",

        closeTabIconSize:100
    })
```

The code above has been written at the top of section 6 (TabSet) in load_skin.js file.

Now, I am still getting the same old TabSet look and feel in MainTabSet.

my Questions now are :

1. did I follow the right steps to achieve my goal ?
2. how could I consider new classes to some sub elements of TabSet -like TabBar- but only for the new component (MainTabSet)?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

According to [last paragraph of the article](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Skinning.html)  that you have mentioned, you were suppose to call  `setScClassName("MainTabSet")` to apply smartClient's js class to your java class. I think that should be something like this:

```
public class MainTabSet extends TabSet{
    public MainTabSet(){
        setScClassName("MainTabSet");
        build();
    }

    private void build(){
        setMargin(6);
        setWidth100();
        setHeight100();  
        setStyleName("nt-main-tabset");
        Tab inboxTab = new Tab("Inbox");
        inboxTab.setPane(new InboxPane().get());
     }
}
```